# A simple MongoDB C++ program does nothing when running

Tags: c++, mongodb

I have the following C++ MongoDB;

```
#include <iostream>

#include <bsoncxx/builder/stream/document.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/json.hpp>

#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/instance.hpp>


int main(int, char**)
{
    std::cout << "\nStart" << std::endl;
    mongocxx::instance inst{};
    mongocxx::client conn{mongocxx::uri{}};

    bsoncxx::builder::stream::document document{};

    auto collection = conn["testdb"]["testcollection"];
    document << "hello" << "world";

    collection.insert_one(document.view());
    auto cursor = collection.find({});

    for (auto&& doc : cursor) {
        std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "end" << std::endl;
}
```

Compilation run fine without errors, but when run from cmd it does nothing at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing your connection didn't work.  Did you check that?

Comment: @AnonMail, at lease first line which prints 'Start' should have run, right? I have a mongod instance running.

Comment: Use your debugger, single step the program.

Comment: Is your mongod running on the default port? Also, can you provide the info of your configuration (OS, compiler, C driver version, C++ driver version, polyfill and version)?

Comment: @Saghm, yes it does.